# Suspend button in Ubuntu Dock on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: suspend, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I have a very different query than suggested questions displayed to me now. I already have access to the '**Suspend**' button when I type *sus* in the dash search.

[image]

I would like to know whether this could be added to the panel as a *favourite*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I don't think you can add *this specific* suspend icon to the dock. But as an alternative, you can create a launcher by hand and add to the dock. To do that, follow the steps below.

1. Create a `.desktop` file (say `suspend-for-dock.desktop`) in `~/.local/share/applications/` directory. You can do that by running the following command in Terminal:

   ```
   touch ~/.local/share/applications/suspend-for-dock.desktop
   ```
2. Open the file with a text editor, for example by running

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/suspend-for-dock.desktop
   ```

   Then add the following lines to the file:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=Suspend for Dock
   Exec=systemctl suspend
   Comment=Suspend icon for Ubuntu dock
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   Icon=/full/path/to/your/preferred/icon-image
   ```
3. Save the file.
4. Click "*Activities*" or "*Show Applications*" and search for "Suspend for Dock". It should appear.
5. Right click and add to favourites.